# how to connect ssh in vm

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine

I have vm inside my ubuntu and i am using reliance netconnnect.
I can use internet but cannoy ssh outside of vm.
I can ssh from vm to outside but not outside to ssh.
ssh and open-ssh already installed.  can anyone tell me what needs to be do?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to through this issue and able to ssh and connect internet, by changing to bridged and ... check this attached [image: snapshot].

ubuntu x68 11.10 in virtualBox.

--
~Subba

Answer (score 0):

Your network-adapter setting for the VM inside your Ubuntu may be set to NAT. This would mean that it has an IP address that is not reachable from outside (i.e. another machine). You could change the setting to Bridged and see if it works for you.

Comment: if i changed to bridge adapter, then it not even getting internet. from NAT atleast i can use intenet from host ubuntu

Comment: Ah, I see; this usually happens when you use a VPN or as in your case when you are directly connected to the ISP (i.e. not through a Wifi Router etc) using the Reliance netconnect. I guess you understand the problem then that your VM's IP address is unreachable. AFAIK, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this so what I found helpful from my google friend :) is below

I had created a Virtual machine on VM workstation of Ubuntu OS and was not able to connect from my windows local machine.

To enable ssh port 22 if in case the port is disabled or the firewall is disabled use below cmd

sudo ufw status

sudo ufw enable
This will enable the firewall

sudo ufw enable ssh #this will enable ssh port for remote SSH terminal connection

I was able to establish the connection from the local windows machine using the Tectia terminal to my VM ubuntu.